Subtração de duas datas, Javascript
Subtração de duas datas para saber.
function Calc() {
let meses = new Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
let dayName = new Array("domingo", "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado");
let agora = new Date();
let DiasDoAno = 365;
//for (let i = 0; i < 364; i++) {
//    DiasDoAno.push(DiasDoAno[i] + 1)
// }
var total = new Date();
var dia_atual = (total.getDate() + "/" + meses[total.getMonth(0)] + "/" + total.getFullYear());

let resp = document.getElementById('saida');
var dia_nasc = new Date();
var date = prompt("Digite a data de ascimento", dia_nasc.getDate() + "/" + meses[dia_nasc.getMonth()] + "/" + dia_nasc.getFullYear());


const datas = new Date(dia_atual) - new Date(date);
const dirença_dias = datas / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
console.log(dirença_dias) // 38


console.log(dia_atual, date)

let idade = dia_atual - date;
let ano1 = [];
let anos_bissextos = [];
let Total_dias = 0; //total de dias até esse dia

let dias_faltam_aniversario = 0;






for (let i = 0; i < idade; i++) {//numero de dias de vida
    ano1.push(ano_nascimento + i)
    Total_dias = DiasDoAno * idade;

}

for (let i = 0; i < idade; i++) {
    if (ano1[i] % 100 != 0 && ano1[i] % 4 == 0 || ano1[i] % 400 == 0) {
        anos_bissextos.push(ano1[i]);//nume;ro de dias de vida
        Total_dias = Total_dias + 1;
    }
}


console.log(Total_dias);
resp.innerHTML = `<p>Um ano tem ${DiasDoAno}, Hoje é dia ${date}, o seja uma ${dayName[dia_nasc.getDate()]} do mês de ${meses[dia_nasc.getMonth()]} do ano 
  de ${dia_nasc.getFullYear()} sua idade é ${idade} e o numero de anos bissextos é ${ano1} e
   os anos bissextos são ${anos_bissextos}
   o total de dias é ${Total_dias}</p`

//se é ano bissexto
//resp.innerHTML = `Chegamos a conclusão, que faltam  ${} dias, e ${} meses
//para completar ${} anos. Seu aniversário vai ser dia ${} do mes ${} no ano de{}, 
//atualmente você tem ${} dias de idade, e faltam ${} dias para o próximo`

}

Esta pergunta já foi postada. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
